# PHP no me va a la funcion jquery que llamo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Llevo poco tiempo trabajando con php y me confundo en muchas cosas.
Tengo un programa php que se llama clasificacion.php que solo lee una tabla con los datos de una tabla de clasificación, el 1er campo es idclaf, que es el código con que identifico a cada equipo y lo utilizo para que por medio de Ajax, conseguir el nombre del equipo en una tabla llamada equipos (no sé si es la mejor manera de hacerlo, me parece que no). Pero cuando llamo a la función para hacer el Ajax , no entra en la función, y por supuesto, no me trae nada. Aquí los 2 códigos:

clasificacion.php

```
     <html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="category" content="Prácticas">

    <title>Tabla de Clasificacion de la Liga de Futbol</title>
    <!-- Declaración de fichero de estilos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilo.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">

            function solicitaNombre(codigo) {
                var parametros = { // pasamos los datos de opcion a parametros
                    "valorCodigo": codigo,
                }
                // aqui comienza a funcionar Ajax
                $.ajax({

                    data: parametros,
                    url: 'buscar_nombre.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function () { // envio de la variable
                        $("#resp").html("Procesando, espere por favor..."); // mientra se procesa envia un mensaje
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        equipo = .html(response);
                        return equipo;
                    }
                })
            }


    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="general">
    <div class="sisnav">
        <span class="notsp00">HOME - &gt;</span>
    </div>
    <?php
    require("cabecera.php")
    ?>
    <div class="caja2">
        <section>
            <div class="cuerpo02">
                <h3>Clasificacion de la liga</h3><br/>
                <?php
                include("conexion.php");
                // selecionamos la base de datos
                if(mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) === TRUE) {


                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clasificacion ORDER BY puntos DESC , dg DESC , gf DESC";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    if ($result) {
                        // Si hay registros
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0) {
                            ?>

                            <table class="clasif" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                                <tr >
                                    <th >Equipo</th>
                                    <th>PJ</th>
                                    <th>G</th>
                                    <th>E</th>
                                    <th>P</th>
                                    <th>GF</th>
                                    <th>GC</th>
                                    <th>DG</th>
                                    <th>PTS</th>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                                    ?>

//aqui llama a la funcion
                                    <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
                                        $( function() {
                                            solicitaNombre(<?php $row['idclaf'];?>);
                                        })
                                    </script>


                                    <tr>
                                        <td>equip</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['jugados'];?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['ganados']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['empatados']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['perdidos']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['gf']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['gc']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['dg']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['puntos']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </table>

                            <?php

                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "error";
                    }
                }



                ?>

            </div>
        </section>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

<?
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

buscar_nombre.php

```
    <?php
if( isset($_POST['valorCodigo']) ) { // Existe valorOpcion, es la variable que viene del ajax
    $codigo = $_POST['valorCodigo'];

    require("conexion.php");
    // selecionamos la base de datos
    if(mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) === TRUE) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT nombre   FROM equipos WHERE idequip = $codigo";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        if ($result2) {
            // Si hay registros
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) !== 0) {
                $fila2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                $equipo=  $fila2['nombre'];
                return $equipo;



            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

.

Comment: No parece muy optimo el codigo. Lo primero mira que relacion tienen las tablas, quizas puedas hacer un join entre ellas y en una consulta sacar la clasificacion y el nombre del equipo. Lo segundo, el success de ajax no es correcto, tu success deberia "escribir" los datos en un div que le indiques (o en varios, eso segun tu programa).

Comment: No tengo muy claro. porque haces una llamada a Ajax?¿ desde mi punto de vista creo que puedes traer el dato que necesitas desde la primer consulta.

Comment: Normalmente Ajax se usa para **una segunda acción** que ejecutas en background sin tener que refrescar la página. Por ejemplo operaciones del tipo CRUD en la base de datos (Crear, Leer, Actualizar, Eliminar). En cualquiera de ellas tendrías un formulario donde recoges los datos y ejecutas cualquiera de las funciones CRUD mediante Ajax. Un hipotético uso de tu caso sería tener un select con todos los ids de clasificaciones y al seleccionar uno llamar a Ajax para que te traiga más datos de **ese** select y te los presente en alguna parte sin tener que refrescar la página.

Comment: El código está un poco revuelto pero está bien hecho, el problema viene en tus Scripts. En la invocación solicitaNombre(<?php $row['idclaf'];?>) Le estás pasando un dato y todo parece correcto para el AJAX tu resultado lo encapsulas en la variable equipo y cuando regresa al script original ya no sabe que hacer con él, es decir, no lo estás mostrado, no lo estás poniendo en un input o div, corrió bien todo, pero al final el dato que trajiste no está representando nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias Muriano, que harias para que no este revuelto el codigo? es cierto lo que dices de lo de la variable de retorno, pero lo que me pasa, o era lo que yo creia, era que no entraba en la funcion.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes el dato, pero no estás haciendo nada con él. Osea invocaste una función, le pasas un parámetro, lo recoje la otra función hace su teatro el AJAX, el valor lo regresas en una variable que se llama equipo y le das return. Regresa al código que invocó la función y ya no haces nada con ese dato.

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
  alert(solicitaNombre(<?php $row['idclaf'];?>));
  $('div').html(solicitaNombre(<?php $row['idclaf'];?>));
});
</script>
```

Haz algo con ese dato...